# Does $\int_a^b \overline{f(z)}\ dz = \int_a^b u(t)\ dt - i \int_a^b v(t)\ dt$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Hypothesis:** Let $[a,b] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $f = u + iv$ with
domain $[a,b]$.

**Question:** Do we have that

$$\int_a^b \overline{f(z)}\ dz = \int_a^b u(t)\ dt + i \int_a^b -v(t)\ dt = \int_a^b u(t)\ dt - i \int_a^b v(t)\ dt$$

given that

$$\overline{f(t)} = \overline{u(t) + i v(t)} = u(t) - iv(t) \text{?}$$

Comment: Yes, it does.$\!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, $\int \overline{f}dx=\overline{\int f dx}=\overline{\int u dx+i\int v dx}=\int u dx-i\int v dx$